# "Your" vs "You are"

Tags: possessives, contractions

Many times I have come across the word *your*. People use it instead of *you are* I guess so. Is it a mistake or has it another special meaning? Now I do not have the exact context but surely I will add it once I get.

Comment: Yes  some context or an example would be nice. Otherwise, people are guessing what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

When you see ***your*** used where ***you are*** is called for, what you are probably seeing is a mis-spelling of the contraction ***you’re***.

This is a very common mistake, among native speakers as well as learners, because in many spoken dialects there is little or no difference between the pronunciations of ***your*** and ***you’re***. In ‘textspeak’, the non-standard spelling employed colloquially in texting and on the internet, they are spelled identically: ***ur***.

Comment: So next time I read that Abraham was from Ur of the Chaldeans, I should ask whether they mean Your of the Chaldeans or You Are of the Chaldeans.

Comment: @Jay  `You Are of the Chaldeans` . but _Ur of the Chaldeans_ in the Bible is a place, _ur_ in this context is not an abbreviation.

Comment: I think it is customary to put a gap between _u_ and _r_ (`u r`) to mean you're.

Comment: I think it's funny that we're (wer? wur? we r?) talking about the customary way to incorrectly spell things in text-speak.

Comment: @makz Umm, yeah. It was a joke.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem People need to know the correct way to spell things incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Very basic question and words are often found incorrectly used by non-natives (In India, I've come across many such examples).

If you read 'your' in place of 'you are' it is either *plain wrong* or you have *misread* it! [For example, on the internet, you also find *loose weight* that does not mean it's correct].

What you have read is [*You're* which is a contraction of *You are*.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/you%27re)

'Your' means something belonging to you and "you are" denotes you, yourself.

> That is *your <del>you are</del>*  car 
>   *You are <del>your</del>* a girl.

Comment: Native speakers have problems with *your* and *you're* too.

Comment: I have a hunch that native speakers make this error more often than non-native speakers. My idea is that it's rare to find a learner who learned English through reading and makes this kind of error. However, due to the popularity of autocorrect programs, I think this error could happen to anyone nowadays.

Comment: Just to quibble: "Loose weight" could be correct in the proper context. Like, "The scale came with a set of weights. Most of these had slots they fit securely into, but there was one loose weight."

Comment: I just saw a statement on another forum where the writer concluded, "Thank you for your patients." Which I guess could make sense if he was a doctor and another doctor had referred patients to him, but that wasn't the context.